# .htaccess - drop/edit/remove query string parameter/flag

Tags: string, .htaccess, edit

I'm trying to turn this:

> /index.php?param1=1&param2=1&param3=1

into this:

> /index.php?param1=1&param3=1

I would have thought this would work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php?(.*)param2=([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php\?$1&$3 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

...but it and other variations are doing sod all :(

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?param2=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.php?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```